# How can I use and call a dll file in my C# program?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I downloaded the program here in this site which is a on screen keyboard.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/touchscreenkeyboard/touchscreenkeyboard_src.zip

Am I right that for me to use this program or to add it in my existing c# program is to use only the dll?

If so how can I call it?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `Solution Explorer,` right Click your `References` under your `Project,` Click `Add Reference`, then Click `Browse`, find your `.dll` file and Add it to your references.

Documentation: [How to: Add and Remove References in Visual Studio (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: @LucasJuan Make sure you include the required namespaces at the top of your file.

Answer (score 2):

[See](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

1. In Solution Explorer, select the project.
2. On the Project menu, click Add Reference.
3. The Add Reference dialog box opens.
4. Select the tab indicating the type of component you want to reference.
5. In the top pane, select the component you want to reference, and then click the Select button. Press CTRL while clicking to select multiple components.

Answer (score 1):

In the Solution Explorer,
Under "References", right Click -> "Add Reference" -> "Browse" to your dll and add.
Now in your code file on the top, Add : "using yourdllname.dll"
And you can use the dll provided functions.